# How to repeat a tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

The `tf.data.Dataset` actually has a `repeat` method that outputs what is much more like a `tile`, ie that:

```
list(tf.data.Dataset.range(2).repeat(3).as_numpy_iterator())
# [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

is like:

```
np.tile(np.arange(2), 3)
# array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

What I am looking for is actual numpy repeat:

```
np.repeat(np.arange(2), 3)
# array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do it as below,

1. Each element is repeated using `tf.repeat` in `map` function.
2. Flatten the result using `flat_map`.

**Code -**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(2).map(lambda x : tf.repeat(x,3)).flat_map(lambda y: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y))

list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())
```

**Output -**

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: a bit heavy it is the solution i am using actually. Just corrected the typo `dataset.from_tensor_slices` so that others can copy/paste!